Error when trying to plot relative abundance using ggplot in R
I am encountering an error while trying to plot relative abundance using ggplot in R. Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

Generated a phyloseq object ps_rar containing OTU table, sample data, taxonomy table, and phylogenetic tree.

Aggregated the taxonomy table at the genus level using tax_glom function from the phyloseq package.

Identified the top 20 genera based on their abundance.

Created a new column Genus_20 in the taxonomy table to store the top 20 genera.

Transformed the sample counts to relative abundance using transform_sample_counts.

Converted the phyloseq object to a data frame using psmelt.

Attempted to plot the relative abundance using ggplot, but consistently return this error message (have tried using multiple different datasets that are working in other R environments)
Error in FUN():
! Don't know how to get height of  object


I am not sure what is causing this error or how to resolve it. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong and how to fix it? I have included a relevant code snippet below for reference - I have been able to replicate the error using phyloseqs GlobalPatterns example dataset:
> library(phyloseq)
> library(ggplot2)
> library(tidyverse)
> library(qiime2R)
> library(microbiome)
> library(ggh4x)
> library(ggtext)
> library(ggplot2)
> library(dplyr)
> library(extrafont)
> library(ggforce)
> library(vegan)
> data(GlobalPatterns)
> # plot the relative abundance of top 20 genera
> ps_Genus <- tax_glom(GlobalPatterns, taxrank = "Genus", NArm = FALSE)
> top20Genus = names(sort(taxa_sums(ps_Genus), TRUE)[1:20])
> taxtab20 = cbind(tax_table(ps_Genus), Genus_20 = NA)
> taxtab20[top20Genus, "Genus_20"] <- as(tax_table(ps_Genus)
+                                        [top20Genus, "Genus"], "character")
> tax_table(ps_Genus) <- tax_table(taxtab20)
> ps_Genus_ra <- transform_sample_counts(ps_Genus, function(x) 100 * x/sum(x))
> df_Genus <- psmelt(ps_Genus_ra)
> df_Genus <- arrange(df_Genus, SampleType)
> df_Genus$Genus_20[is.na(df_Genus$Genus_20)] <- c("Other")
> supp_RAAE <- df_Genus %>%
+   mutate(Genus_20 = reorder(Genus_20, -Abundance)) %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = SampleType, y = Abundance, fill = Genus_20)) +
+   geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
+   facet_nested(~ SampleType, scales = "free", space = "free") +
+   labs(x = "SampleType", y = "Relative abundance") +
+   theme( 
+     axis.text.y = element_text(size=16, face = 'bold'),
+     axis.title.y = element_text(size=16, face = 'bold'),
+     axis.ticks.y = element_line(linewidth = 1),
+     axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
+     axis.text.x = element_blank(),
+     axis.title.x = element_blank(),
+     legend.title = element_blank(),
+     legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
+     legend.position = "bottom",
+     strip.background = element_blank(),
+     strip.text = element_textbox_simple(
+       padding = margin(5, 0, 5, 0),
+       margin = margin(5, 5, 5, 5),
+       size = 10,
+       face = "bold",
+       halign = 0.5,
+       fill = "white",
+       box.color = "grey",
+       linewidth = 1.5,
+       linetype = "solid",),
+     panel.background = element_blank()
+   )
> supp_RAAE

Error in `FUN()`:
! Don't know how to get height of <integer> object
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! I am running R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt) -- "Puppy Cup".
Error in `FUN()`:
    ! Don't know how to get height of <integer> object
    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `FUN()`:
! Don't know how to get height of <integer> object
---
    Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(data)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built(data)
  5.     └─layout$render(geom_grobs, data, theme, plot$labels)
  6.       └─ggplot2 (local) render(..., self = self)
  7.         └─self$facet$draw_panels(...)
  8.           └─ggh4x (local) draw_panels(..., self = self)
  9.             └─strip$setup(layout, params, theme, type = "grid")
 10.               └─ggh4x (local) setup(..., self = self)
 11.                 └─self$get_strips(...)
 12.                   └─ggh4x (local) get_strips(..., self = self)
 13.                     └─self$build_strip(x, labeller, theme, TRUE, params, layout_x)
 14.                       └─ggh4x (local) build_strip(..., self = self)
 15.                         └─self$assemble_strip(labels, "top", elem, params, layout)
 16.                           └─ggh4x (local) assemble_strip(..., self = self)
 17.                             └─ggproto_parent(Strip, self)$assemble_strip(...)
 18.                               └─ggh4x (local) assemble_strip(..., self = self)
 19.                                 └─self$draw_labels(labels, elems, position, layer_id = index, size = params$size)
 20.                                   └─ggh4x (local) draw_labels(...)
 21.                                     └─base::lapply(split(height, layer_id[!zeros]), max_height)
 22.                                       └─ggplot2 (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 23.                                         ├─base::unlist(lapply(grobs, height_cm))
 24.                                         └─base::lapply(grobs, height_cm)
 25.                                           └─ggplot2 (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)


Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset. As is we can't run your code and figure out what's the issue.

Thank you Stefan! I have updated my question to include the code, using phyloseq's example dataset GlobalPatterns.

The issue is that the CRAN version of ggh4x does not support ggtext::element_textbox_simple or ggtext::element_markdown (see this related and closed GH issue). But that is fixed in the dev version, i.e. run devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x") and your code runs fine: https://i.sstatic.net/ozxhZCA4.png

This was the fix - thank you Stefan!!!
